# setup localStorage for testing React app with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have created an empty application with `create-react-app`. it provides a test script at pckage.json and a sample App.test.js. at the first step, I want to set up the test environment according to the documentation of [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#srcsetuptestsjs-1). in my app I will use localStorage.
let's say an action like below to be tested

```
export const cancel = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("MyAppData");
  return { type: types.USER_CANCEL};
};
```

besides the enzyme part, it shows how to initialize `localStorage`. so I ended up with a `setupTests.js` file like

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
// react-testing-library renders your components to document.body,
// this will ensure they're removed after each test.
import "react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each";
// this adds jest-dom's custom assertions
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn()
};
global.localStorage = localStorageMock;
```

here if I do not import `jest` from jest or jest-dom or jest-enzyme, ESLinter shows an error in `jest.fn()` that jest is not defined. when I import and run `yarn test` I get

```
$ react-scripts test --env=jsdom
 FAIL  src\App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _jest2.default.fn is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/setupTests.js:15:27)
          at <anonymous>
```

I really dont get from QAs here and in other forums how should I setup localStorage for testing.

Comment: I'm not sure why jest isn't available in setupTests, but I'm quite sure that it should be imported as `import * as jest from 'jest'` and not `import jest from 'jest'` as you likely tried. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: @estus not reaaly but error changed to TypeError: jest.fn is not a function

Comment: for eslint error add eslint config "env": { "jest":true}

Comment: how to deal in service which get data from localStorae ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not know what exactly happened, some packages related to jest, jet-dom, jest-enzyme was mkaing a conflict. but I managed to make it work after deleting package-lock.json, yarn.lock, node_modules, removing jest from the dependencies in package.json, then doing npm install and yarn install!

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to import jest into your test files.

You should instead tell eslint what [Environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) it should expect in the file so it knows what globals are present.

Add this to the top of any files where you use jest globals

```
/* eslint-env jest */
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not really with eslint I can disable it for whole file. I just mentioned that to say that jest is not by default on the scope